# Length of longest palindrome list in a linked list using O(1) extra space

Tags: data-structures

I am trying to understand the logic for this question from geeks of geeks.
Can someone help me to understand the solution provided there.

```
Below is the link :
  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-longest-palindrome-list-linked-list-using-o1-extra-space/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
      prev curr next
       ||   ||   ||
       \/   \/   \/
   2 <- 4 <- 3    4 -> 2 ->15
```

The idea is that you maintain three pointers where `curr` points to the head of a linked list going in reverse direction (as above), and `next` is the head pointer to another linked list going in the forward direction.

You then check for odd length palindrome where you start the comparison from `prev` and `next`, since there is no need to check for middle val in a odd-length palindrome. Similarly, if the palindrome is even, you start with `curr` and `next`. The end result is the max of two different checks.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ... It will be much helpful. :)